# Как работает glTexImage2D?

Tags: opengl, glsl

есть `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);` где `data` - `unsigned char*`.

Я знаю что эта функция загружает наже изображение в память GPU. Знаю, что 3 аргумент - это то, как данные должны быть предсавлены в GPU, а 7 и 8 то как они представленны в передаваемом нами массиве.

Я не могу понять следующие вещи:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что так как мы указали в качестве 7 аргумента `GL_RGB`, то все наши данные в массиве будут переведены из диапозона от 0 до 255 в диапозон от 0 до 1?
2. В документации написано, что в качестве седьмого параметра можно передать например такой аргумент: `GL_RGB_INTEGER`. Что это значит? Зачем нам здесь указывать тип если мы его указываем в восьмом параметре?
3. В документации написано, что в качестве 3 аргумента можно передать огромное количество различных параметров. Меня интересует различие например между `GL_RGB` и `GL_RGB8`. Я могу предположить, что `GL_RGB8` означает, что на каждый цвет у нас будет уделён 1 байт, но, что тогда означает `GL_RGB`?

Comment: @user7860670 В [этой документации](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)? Про `GL_RGB_INTEGER` я там ничего не вижу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да в этой. Воспользуйтесь поиском по странице...

Comment: @user7860670 Воспользовался. Вижу `The following symbolic values are accepted: ... GL_RGB_INTEGER`. Что он делает - не написано. Дальше ищу по слову "integer", может они все вместе описаны? Нет, тоже ничего.

Comment: @VanechikSpace Сходу могу сказать только про (1) - да, но не из-за `GL_RGB`, а из-за `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` (вместо какого-нибудь `GL_FLOAT`). Но скорее всего при чтении, а не сразу при вызове `glTexImage2D`. Остальное надо вот отсюда вычитывать: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf